# Working ArrayList<File> and String[]

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<File>` and also a `String[]`, How can I add the `String[]` in `ArrayList<File>`?

Comment: A `String[]` is not a `File`, so why would you want to do that?

Comment: What do these `String[]` contain, paths, content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (String s : stringArray) fileList.add(new File(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] strings = {"foo", "bar"};

list.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
```

I have assumed you have a list of file paths. If not, I like Marko's answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the (apparently nonsensical) question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I took a lucky shot. He may have meant a List of file paths. Who knows

Comment: @Bohemian You do need to add into a File list. Take your lucky shot from there :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Let's face it, the question is rubbish anyway. I'll give you a +1 though :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to do, you cannot simply add `String` to a collection of `File`, since `File` is not a super class of `String`.

Do these `String[]` contain

1. Paths to files of yours?
2. Content which should be represented by a file?

**Assuming 1.** you can simply add them by using the appropriate `File` constructor:

```
String[] paths = // ...
for (String path : paths) {
     fileList.add(new File(path));
}
```

Otherwise, **assuming 2.** that these `String[]` contain content of a file, you could simply create a `File` in Java, write the content into it and add the `File` object afterwards to your `fileList` as shown above.

Creating and writing to a file goes like this:

```
String text = "This is your text file";
Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
File file = new File("filename.txt");
writer.write(text);
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add String objecten to a File List

Comment: I don't know why you have a -1, you are correct.. However, provide a solution, and not just a comment.

Comment: Well the question doesn't state anythng usefull